# The number 3 is not displayed in the Panel's clock applet

Tags: 12.10, panel, clock

See image. This is how the current time is displayed -- the '3' from '13:39:22' and '2:57:31pm' is missing... Any idea how to fix this?

(It seems to have started yesterday after last upgrade.)

Clock at time '13:49:22' :

[image: broken clock]

Clock at time '2:57:31pm':

[image]

List of apt sources in use (It could do with a cleanup, I guess.):

```
user@host:~$ grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* -h
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu quantal main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner #Added by software-center
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner #Added by software-center
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner #Added by software-center
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/scopes-packagers/ppa/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu quantal main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu quantal main
```

Comment: Which repositories do you use?

Comment: See question edit -- also I'm not on 13.04, but on 12.10.

Comment: This won't be the cause, but I would remove the line `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner #Added by software-center`

Comment: Added an image: it appears my '3' is broken... odd.

Comment: You seem to have lost the '4' as well. Does this still happen after a reboot? Do these characters still appear in other parts of the UI  (e.g. showing date stamps in Nautilus)?

Comment: Sorry, the first time should've read '13:39:22'.

Comment: Reboot fixed it.